# Can the DM be a Custom created Patron for a Warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I've been theory-crafting this idea with my players for a while now and we wondered if it is possible for the DM to be a Patron for a Warlock. As far as I know, in XGtE it is written that you can create a custom Patron.

Is there a rule against the DM being an entity in the game which empowers a player (in this example a warlock) while being the DM in the same place (so they'd have two roles to play at the same time)?

Also we were wondering what special powers the player gets from his Patron. How does this interfere with the game itself?

But I guess that no Warlock Player wants to have their patron sitting OoC next to them.

Comment: It's your game; you can do pretty much whatever you want. If you want to know whether doing so will adversely affect your game, you'd need to tell us a bit more about how it would work - what does it mean for the character to have the DM as a patron?

Comment: "Patron of the Fourth Wall"

Comment: Hey, CrH! We've put your question on hold for now. In this case, that means that no more answers can be submitted. We did this because we feel that we need more information from you to get proper answer to the question. For example see @JeffZeitlin's comment above. We simply need more details about the way you want this to work before we can explain the potential consequences in-game.

Comment: ["Look! A *Dungeons & Dragons* ride…!"](https://youtu.be/3JjhQ1Oi_3k)

Comment: With the edit, it seems like you may be opening up a new question. Are you now focused just on "RAW, can the DM be an in-game entity?"

Comment: In most games the DM is responsible for playing all of the world's characters outside of the player's own PCs. That means that, whenever narratively necessary, a Warlocks patron is already normally played by the DM. In what way do you intend that the DM actually *being* a PCs patron would differ from the DM simply *playing* the PC's patron, as per normal?

Comment: Related on [Are there rules to make my own warlock pact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148887/are-there-rules-to-make-my-own-warlock-pact)

Comment: @Tiggerous If I could award bounty on a comment, I would!

Comment: As well as the comments here, you may find the answers at https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/should-a-gm-be-a-player relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the GM you can allow any homebrew patron for your warlocks. You would need to decide what powers are granted to the players (you can work with the players on this, but the GM should get the final word).

However, keep in mind that patrons are usually in-game entities, so you would have to either create an appropriate omnipotent entity in your game world, or get meta and have it actually be the out-of-game GM. In the latter case check with your players as it can be immersion-breaking.

Comment: It might be fun to have a 4th wall break, of a GM patron.  If you group is into Deadpool...

Comment: Yeah, I know at my table we've done some similar stuff in another system, but I've played with people who would be completely put off by that kind of thing (which is fine too)

Comment: If you're happy with just re-skinning exisitng game content, rather than inventing new mechanics, I wonder of the GOO patron would be the closest fit for the right sort of feel?